# asp.net mvc fckeditor upload image error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, file-upload, fckeditor, image-uploading

has anyone been able to get it to work with asp.net mvc ?

changed the extension in config to .aspx

there's a asp.net control as referred here
http://forums.asp.net/t/1060019.aspx

but haven't seen any asp.net control usage in mvc
is it possible if there's no viewstate required ?

anyone been able to configure fckeditor to uploading images in asp.net mvc ? how ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this project in Code project: [Integrating FCKeditor in ASP.NET MVC](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/fckeditor.aspx)

[image: Screenshot]

<s>Edit: Moderator: Why the screenshot is not working? It works in the  preview.</s>
Works now. I guess you need to add text after the image